# How can you adjust chromeOptions zoom levels without worrying about this id needing to be passed in?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to set chrome's zoom level upon opening. I realize there are ways to send keys to zoom, change viewport, and change browser size, but with the machine running our tests, the browser is not in the foreground to receive the keys, and the browser and viewport sizes are limited by the machines resolution. I also realize this breaks clicks, as webdriver cannot find the correct coordinates. With that in mind, proceeding!

My solution has been to change the browsers per_host_zoom_levels. To find this example, I checked my own chrome preferences here:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

I found that passing in the per_host_zoom_levels does in fact work like so:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

    'chromeOptions':{
        prefs:{
            "partition": {
                "per_host_zoom_levels": {
                    "14692111032568906945": {
                        "localhost":-3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

This gets the browser to use a different zoom level on any localhost addresses, which is exactly what I need for the test.

The issue is the 'id' of sorts that is directly under the per_host_zoom_levels. It is different for each machine, and in fact mine even has three different ids of sorts.

Is there a way to make this generic so it sets the zoom level no matter what the 'id' is?

Comment: Where is this `id` value coming from, how did you get that? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I opened up my own preferences file to get this value. C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences. Sorry for not initially mentioning it. Under preferences, I found the zoom settings, and found I could pass them into the chromeOptions successfully. How this id is generated, I do not know :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to  retrieve the "id" from the machine's chrome preferences before executing the tests.